# Disable delete row in transaction's grids

Tags: genexus

I need to disable o remove the "x" (delete) icon in transaction's grid.

Genexus X Ev.3 U1

[image: Delete icon example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including an error rule conditioned to delete mode.

Something like:
error("cannot delete")  if delete and level(ArticuloDescripcion);

Answer (score 0):

You can change the visibility value to false in the CSS class of the item. In this case I think that the CSS class is called "DeleteAttribute".
The CSS configuration is in KB Explorer -> Customization -> Themes -> your_theme_name.

Comment: How can change this property in runtime?

Comment: You have to identify the object name of this icon. After that you have to use this code: objname.Visible = 0